Mathematical relation of RMS to PK-PK for noise
RMS is root mean square, peak to peak is the difference between peaks of a signal.
In the video and other places, they say the 1 mVRMS = 6.6 mVpk-pk.
The reason is 6.6 standard deviations covers 99% of the signal.
How does standard deviation link to pk-pk value mathematically?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-KcODSYXiZA


This all depends on your/his assumptions which are not given for time duration and BW and spectral shape.  Compare pp/rms to 2log (BW time) product?  I have often used longer-term Vpp measurements than his assumption and used RMS=10% Vpp for noise in audio and data and 35.5% for a sine or 1/2* 2^-1


How standard deviation links to pk-pk value mathematically?

It doesn't. Unless you make some assumptions.
Even if you model the noise as a well-defined mathematical process, choosing for instance the Additive Gaussian White Noise model, even then the peak value is unbounded, if the observation interval is long enough. While AWGN happens to be quite a good noise model in many situations, it's not valid automatically, or everywhere.
That's why for serious work, we use the RMS value of the noise. In most applications, the signal energy and the noise energy are what go into the bit error rate calculations. We do have models for noise where the long term average power is well defined.
To informally convert between one and the other, we need to make assumptions that we are only interested in a level not exceeded 95% or 99% of the time, or that we can see what 3 standard deviations looks like on an oscilloscope. You have used one of those conversions in your question. It's only useful to you if it reflects how your system behaves, and what's important to you. If a peak value might corrupt a bit in a error corrected system, then one or two standard deviations may be OK. If a peak sets off a bomb that wipes out your country, then 6 standard deviations may still not be enough.
Perhaps the most consistent and transparent way to try to relate rms and peak measures is to use the Cummulative Distribution Function of the noisy signal, or of the added noise. This gives you the probability that any given level will be exceeded. In addition, comparing the shape of this curve to your assumption about what the distribution of the noise is will tell you whether your assumption is valid or not. It's especially useful to plot the complement of the curve, with a log scale on the probability, to let you see the shape of the very low probability tail.

Hello, standart deviation is a statistical term, pk-pk is not.
RMS is not statistics.
So what that all the signal lies withing 6 standard deviations ,how does this assumption tell us that 1Vrms=6.6Vpk-pk

@scot123 1 V rms is only 6.6 V pk-pk IF YOU MAKE THE ASSUMPTION that 1 V rms is 6.6 V pk-pk. If you make other assumptions, then it isn't.

@Neil_UK, As far as broadband noise is concerned, this is not really a assumption. It's an equality.

@scot123 For periodic signals, RMS may be considered non-statistical. For everything else, including (and especially) noise, RMS is completely and utterly statistical.

Update following OP's question A few more explanations.
Let's compare the standard deviation formula in discrete time.
$$
\sigma =\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\left [ \left ( x_{1}-\mu  \right )^{2} + \left (  x_{2}-\mu \right )^{2} + \left ( x_{3}-\mu \right )^{2} +\cdots + \left ( x_{n}-\mu \right )^{2} \right]}
$$
where the mean µ equal to
$$
\mu  =\frac{1}{n} \left ( x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} +\cdots + x_{n} \right )
$$
with the RMS formula in discrete time.
$$
x_{RMS} =\sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \left (  x{_{1}}^{2} + x{_{2}}^{2} + x{_{3}}^{2} +\cdots + x{_{n}}^{2}\right)}
$$
You'll notice that if mean µ is zero, then
$$
x_{RMS}=\sigma
$$
And only when the mean is zero !
Broadband noise (or thermal noise) follows a normal center of distribution whose mean value is zero (which is not the case for all noises). This type of noise can be analyzed taking into account the simplification:
RMS value = 1σ
Xn = peakpeak noise value

You can therefore use the 68–95–99.7 statistic rule see Wikipedia. This principle is used in the book : Operational Amplifier Noise: Techniques and Tips for Analyzing and Reducing Noise
$$
Probability\ (\mu -3\sigma \leqslant Noise_{peak peak} \leq \mu +3\sigma)= 99.73\%
$$
$$
Probability\ (\mu -3.3\sigma \leqslant Noise_{peak peak} \leq \mu +3.3\sigma)= 99.9\%
$$


Hello, standart deviation is a statistical term, pk-pk is not.
RMS is not statistics.
So what that all the signal lies withing 6 standard deviations ,how does this assumption tell us that 1Vrms=6.6Vpk-pk

@scot123, I've updated my message to reflect your question.

Hello , yes I understand that RMS=standart deviation when mean =0.
why standart RMS=6pk-pk.
we assume that standart deviation is 6pk-pk?

@scot123, Take a look at my image "Time Domain - White noise". 6.6 standard deviations (+3.3 standard deviations / - 3.3 standard deviations) covers 99.9% of the signal peak to peak. Therefore 100µVRMS, for example, equal to 660µVpp. When you will make calculations on noise, you'll use RMS values, but it's useful to know what your RMS value is worth in peak-peak terms.
